# Execute Laravel/Symfony/Artisan Command in Background not working on live

Tags: laravel, symfony-process

I am using Laravel symfony process for background call in laravel on linux server. I have created artisan commands which takes long time to execute, so I have situation to call artisan command on background on button click. I got the solution but that worked on localhost not aws server.

I have used below solution:-

```
 $process = new Process('php artisan '.$task->command.' '.$task->parameters.' > /dev/null 2>&1 &','/var/www/html/datamanager/');
        $process->start();
```

It's working fine on local but not working on live server(linux aws server)

```
 $process = new Process('php artisan '.$task->command.' '.$task->parameters.' > /dev/null 2>&1 &','/var/www/html/datamanager/');
        $process->start();
        return $process->getOutput();
```

Comment: That's probably because the `/var/www/html/datamanager` folder that you use to host the app on your pc is not on the server.

Comment: its already on server